# Add current limiters to data pins

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-protection

I have a hobby project powered by a micro-controller (particle photon if you must know). One of the features is 3.3V, 100mA max output. Each digital data input is able to drain or source a max of 25 mA. It communicates over:

- I2C
- SPI
- analog GPIO
- digital GPIO

I am currently rapid prototyping on a breadboard. Would it be sensible to add resistors to any digital pin and 3.3V out to protect the board? Almost all auxiliary equipment is CMOS and I only need a switching frequency of 1 kHz (save for I2C and SPI). According to the datasheets all auxiliary equipment should use less than 20 mA of the 3V3 rail (save for burts of course).

My question: is something like the drawn circuit below sensible? Could it be an issue that Vdata is higher than Vin?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbcLQp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If all your stuff is CMOS, and you need to protect the uC, it could make sense. If there's a possibility you'll need to add something that actually draws current, then no

Comment: Is "Vdata is higher than Vin?" or was that a guess. If you use twisted pairs on a long cable, you will get less ringing with 50 to 100 Ohms in series from 50 Ohm CMOS drivers (if 74HC') to 120 ohm UTP wire.

Comment: General rule: don't exceed the maximum voltages as stated in the datasheet (usually: -0.3 V < \$V_{IO}\$ < supply voltage + 0.3 V) and nothing should break. So you appear to have a sensor outputting a higher voltage than the supply voltage of the uC. That can violate the uC's maximum ratings! As long as you **limit the current** this can work and not cause damage. But 150  ohm is too low, I would use at least 1 kohm.

Comment: What is R2 doing? a 33 ohm in series with the 3.3 V supply of the uC? That makes no sense. **Can you explain what R2 is doing.** What is the \$V_{in}\$ going to the Sensors?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie. R2 was set to limit the absolute output current to 100 mA. The general idea being: if there is a short after the resistor sensors would stop working and I did not fry the outgoing power-supply.

Comment: *R2 was set to limit the absolute output current to 100 mA* Hmm, you're over-worrying about shorts, CMOS outputs are short circuit proof as long as you don't let the short-circuit current run for hours/days. Adding a resistor in series with  supply is **NEVER** a good idea as a supply voltage must be **stable** and adding a resistor makes it unstable. No one does this and for good reason.

Comment: I agree the current limiter might cause signal integrity issues from dynamic load swings and load regulation error. If these are all Arduino Nano sized sensors, your ground plane is more important on a breadboard.

Comment: If you're still worrying about short circuits then do what all experienced designers do and limit the power / current that goes into the complete design, that is: use a **current limited power supply**. Set it to a maximum current of 100 mA (I'm assuming all circuits and sensors etc consume less than 100 mA in total). An alternative is to use a fuse (of 100 mA) or self-restting fuse (polyfuse) in series with your supply. That can save your day. Resistors in series with supplies generally **ruin your day**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie. Got it. That makes sense. Also, I would accept that comment as an answer, if you want to create one of it.

Comment: That's OK, I've steered you in the right direction (I hope). But you can also write an answer yourself and summarize what you've learned! Feel free to copy-paste from my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a resistor to protect the on the digital data pins is not an issue as normally very little current is transported in modern CMOS logic. However, the same cannot be said for the power supply. In the example above this could still lead to a voltage drop of around 800 mV. Which could lead to a [brownout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownout_(electricity)).

As suggested in the comments, I'll answer my own question. Please feel free to add more details if you deem necessary.